# Loading xmm register with two UInt64s that are in a pointed to array

Tags: delphi, x86, delphi-xe6, sse2

I'm trying to load a 128-bit `xmm` register with two `UInt64` integer in Delphi (XE6).

### Background

An XMM register is 128-bits, and can be loaded with multiple, independent, integers. You can then have the CPU add those multiple integers all in parallel.

For example you can load up xmm0 and xmm1 with four UInt32s each, and then have the CPU add all four pairs simultaneously.

```
xmm0: $00001000 $00000100 $00000010 $00000001
          +         +         +         +      
xmm1: $00002000 $00000200 $00000020 $00000002
          =         =         =         =
xmm0: $00003000 $00000300 $00000030 $00000003
```

After loading xmm0 and xmm0, you perform the add of the four pairs using:

```
paddd xmm0, xmm1    //Add packed 32-bit integers (i.e. xmm0 := xmm0 + xmm1)
```

You could also do it using 8 x 16-bit integers:

```
xmm0: $001F $0013 $000C $0007 $0005 $0003 $0002 $0001
        +     +     +     +     +     +     +     + 
xmm1: $0032 $001F $0013 $000C $0007 $0005 $0003 $0002
        =     =     =     =     =     =     =     = 
xmm0: $0051 $0032 $001F $0013 $000C $0007 $0005 $0003
```

With the instruction

```
paddw xmm0, xmm1  //Add packed 16-bit integers
```

## Now for 64-bit integers

To load two 64-bit integers into an `xmm` register, you have to use either:

- movdqu: Move double-quadword (unaligned)
- movdqa: Move double-quadword (aligned)

In this simple example we won't worry about our UInt64s being aligned, and we'll simply use the *unaligned* version (`movdqu`)

The first thing that we have to deal with is that the Delphi compiler **knows** that **`movdqu`** needs a 128-bit *something* to load - it's loading **double** quadwords.

For this we will create a 128-bit structure, which also nicely lets us address the two 64-bit values:

```
TDoubleQuadword = packed record
   v1: UInt64; //value 1
   v2: UInt64; //value 2
end;
```

And now we can use this type in a test console app:

```
procedure Main;
var
    x, y: TDoubleQuadword;
begin
    //[1,5] + [2,7] = ?
    x.v1 := $0000000000000001;
    x.v2 := $0000000000000005;

    y.v1 := $0000000000000002;
    y.v2 := $0000000000000007;

    asm
        movdqu xmm0, x      //move unaligned double quadwords (xmm0 := x)
        movdqu xmm1, y      //move unaligned double quadwords (xmm1 := y)

        paddq  xmm0, xmm1   //add packed quadword integers    (xmm0 := xmm0 + xmm1)

        movdqu x, xmm0      //move unaligned double quadwords (x := xmm0)

    end;

    WriteLn(IntToStr(x.v1)+', '+IntToSTr(x.v2));
end;
```

And this works, printing out:

```
3, 12
```

### Eye on the prize

With an eye towards the goal of having the x and y be aligned (*but not a necessary part of my question*), lets say we have a **pointer** to a `TDoubleQuadword` structure:

```
TDoubleQuadword = packed record
   v1: UInt64; //value 1
   v2: UInt64; //value 2
end;
PDoubleQuadword = ^TDoubleQuadword;
```

we now change up our *hypothetical test* function to use `PDoubleQuadword`:

```
procedure AlignedStuff;
var
    x, y: PDoubleQuadword;
begin
    x := GetMemory(sizeof(TDoubleQuadword));
    x.v1 := $0000000000000001;
    x.v2 := $0000000000000005;

    y := GetMemory(sizeof(TDoubleQuadword));
    y.v1 := $0000000000000002;
    y.v2 := $0000000000000007;

    asm
        movdqu xmm0, x      //move unaligned double quadwords (xmm0 := x)
        movdqu xmm1, y      //move unaligned double quadwords (xmm1 := y)

        paddq  xmm0, xmm1       //add packed quadword integers    (xmm0 := xmm0 + xmm1)
        movdqu x, xmm0         //move unaligned double quadwords (v1 := xmm0)
    end;

    WriteLn(IntToStr(x.v1)+', '+IntToSTr(x.v2));
end;
```

Now this doesn't compile, and it makes sense why:

```
movdqu xmm0, x      //E2107 Operand size mismatch
```

That makes sense. The `x` argument **must** be 128-bits, and the compiler knows that `x` is really only a (32-bit) pointer.

### But what should it be?

Now we come to my question: what should it be? I've randomly mashed various things on my keyboard, hoping that the compiler gods would just accept what i obviously mean. But nothing works.

```
//Don't try to pass the 32-bit pointer itself, pass the thing it points to:
movdqu xmm0, x^     //E2107 Operand size mismatch    

//Try casting it
movdqu xmm0, TDoubleQuadword(x^) //E2105 Inline assembler error

//i've seen people using square brackets to mean "contents of":
movdqu xmm0, [x]     //E2107 Operand size mismatch
```

And now we give up on rational thought

```
movdqu xmm0, Pointer(x)
movdqu xmm0, Addr(x^)
movdqu xmm0, [Addr(x^)]
movdqu xmm0, [Pointer(TDoubleQuadword(x))^]
```

I did get one thing to compile:

```
movdqu xmm0, TDoubleQuadword(x)
```

But of course that loads the **address** of `x` into the register, rather than the values inside x.

So i give up.

## Complete Minimal Example

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
     TDoubleQuadword = packed record
         v1: UInt64; //value 1
         v2: UInt64; //value 2
     end;
     PDoubleQuadword = ^TDoubleQuadword;

    TVectorUInt64 = array[0..15] of UInt64;
    PVectorUInt64 = ^TVectorUInt64;

 procedure AlignedStuff;
 var
    x, y: PVectorUInt64;
 begin
    x := GetMemory(sizeof(TVectorUInt64));
    //x[0] := ...
    //x[1] := ...
    // ...
    //x[3] := ...
    x[4] := $0000000000000001;
    x[5] := $0000000000000005;

    y := GetMemory(sizeof(TVectorUInt64));
    //y[0] := ...
    //y[1] := ...
    // ...
    //y[3] := ...
    y[4] := $0000000000000002;
    y[5] := $0000000000000007;

    asm
        movdqu xmm0, TDoubleQuadword(x[4])      //move unaligned double quadwords (xmm0 := x)
        movdqu xmm1, TDoubleQuadword(y[4])      //move unaligned double quadwords (xmm1 := y)

        paddq  xmm0, xmm1       //add packed quadword integers    (xmm0 := xmm0 + xmm1)
        movdqu TDoubleQuadword(x[4]), xmm0         //move unaligned double quadwords (v1 := xmm0)
    end;

    WriteLn(IntToStr(x[4])+', '+IntToSTr(x[5]));
 end;

begin
  try
        AlignedStuff;
        Writeln('Press enter to close...');
        Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

## Pointer?

The reason the question is asking about pointers is because:

- you cannot use stack variables (Delphi doesn't guarantee alignment of stack variables)
- you could copy them into a register (e.g. EAX), but then you're doing a wasted copy and function call
- i already have the data aligned in memory

If i give an example of the code that just involves adding UInt64s:

```
TVectorUInt64 = array[0..15] of UInt64;
PVectorUInt64 = ^TVectorUInt64;

var
   v: PVectorUInt64;
begin
   v := GetMemoryAligned(sizeof(TVectorUInt64), 64); //64-byte alignment

   //v is initalized

   for i := 0 to 15 do
   begin
      v[0] := v[0] + v[4];
      v[1] := v[1] + v[5];
      v[2] := v[2] + v[6];
      v[3] := v[3] + v[7];

      //..and some more changes to v0..v3
      //..and some more changes to v12..v15

      v[8]  := v[8]  + v[12];
      v[9]  := v[9]  + v[13];
      v[10] := v[10] + v[14];
      v[11] := v[11] + v[15];

      //...and some more changes to v4..v7

      v[0] := v[0] + v[4];
      v[1] := v[1] + v[5];
      v[2] := v[2] + v[6];
      v[3] := v[3] + v[7];

      //...and some more changes to v0..v3
      //...and some more changes to v12..v15

      v[8]  := v[8]  + v[12];
      v[9]  := v[9]  + v[13];
      v[10] := v[10] + v[14];
      v[11] := v[11] + v[15];

      //...and some more changes to v4..v7

      v[0] := v[0] + v[4];
      v[1] := v[1] + v[5];
      v[2] := v[2] + v[6];
      v[3] := v[3] + v[7];

      //..and some more changes to v0..v3
      //..and some more changes to v12..v15

      v[8]  := v[8]  + v[12];
      v[9]  := v[9]  + v[13];
      v[10] := v[10] + v[14];
      v[11] := v[11] + v[15];

      //...and some more changes to v4..v7

      v[0] := v[0] + v[4];
      v[1] := v[1] + v[5];
      v[2] := v[2] + v[6];
      v[3] := v[3] + v[7];

      //...and some more changes to v0..v3
      //...and some more changes to v12..v15

      v[8]  := v[8]  + v[12];
      v[9]  := v[9]  + v[13];
      v[10] := v[10] + v[14];
      v[11] := v[11] + v[15];

      //...and some more changes to v4..v7
   end;
```

It is conceptually very easy to change the code to:

```
      //v[0] := v[0] + v[4];
      //v[1] := v[1] + v[5];
      asm
         movdqu xmm0, v[0]
         movdqu xmm1, v[4]
         paddq xmm0, xmm1
         movdqu v[0], xmm0
      end
      //v[2] := v[2] + v[6];
      //v[3] := v[3] + v[7];
      asm
         movdqu xmm0, v[2]
         movdqu xmm1, v[6]
         paddq xmm0, xmm1
         movdqu v[2], xmm0
      end

      //v[8]  := v[8]  + v[12];
      //v[9]  := v[9]  + v[13];
      asm
         movdqu xmm0, v[8]
         movdqu xmm1, v[12]
         paddq xmm0, xmm1
         movdqu v[8], xmm0
      end
      //v[10] := v[10] + v[14];
      //v[11] := v[11] + v[15];
      asm
         movdqu xmm0, v[10]
         movdqu xmm1, v[14]
         paddq xmm0, xmm1
         movdqu v[10], xmm0
      end
```

The trick is getting the Delphi compiler to accept it.

- it works for immediate data
- it fails for pointer to data
- and you would think `[contentsOfSquareBrackets]` would work

## Bonus Chatter

Using David's solution (of function calling overhead) leads to a performance improvement of -7%  (90 MB/s -> 83 MB/s of algorithm throughput)

It seems like, in the XE6 compiler, it is valid to conceptually call:

```
movdqu xmm0, TPackedQuadword
```

but the compiler just doesn't have the brains to let you perform the conceptual call:

```
movdqu xmm0, PPackedQuadword^
```

or it's moral equivalent.

If that's the answer, don't be afraid of it. Embrace it, and put it as the form of an answer:

> *"The compiler does not support dereferencing a pointer inside an **`asm`** block. No matter if you try that with a caret (`^`), or square brackets (`[...]`). It just cannot be done.

If that's the answer: answer it.

If it's not the case, and the compiler **can** support pointers in an `asm` block, then post the answer.

Comment: 32 bit code? Why do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have 32-bit applications that use SSE.  Why not do that?

Comment: @J... Because I'd expect a 64 bit process to be faster.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 64-bit is not always an option.

Comment: Just for the record, if the Delphi compiler can use 32-bit `add/adc` on its own, that's potentially still more efficient than having to store/reload to pass data through memory, especially if this asm function can't actually inline so there's `call` overhead as well.  You'll need to write bigger loops in asm for this to not suck, and amortize the call + pointer-setup overhead by looping over a whole array in asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes The code already is unrolled to a large extent: 8 function calls were converted to 8 blocks of code. The canonical 32-bit C implementation can get 648 MB/s - Delphi gets 90 MB/s. The [algorithm](https://blake2.net/) so that it can take advantage of SIMD. And we all know Delphi is much slower than every other compiler, but 86% slower is quite enough.

Comment: I was commenting on the answers that show a whole `AddDoubleQuadword` function that just does one `paddq`.  You probably can't just naively use that.  If you're unrolling inside an asm block or otherwise somehow creating efficient machine code that avoids that much overhead then you're fine.  (I've never used Delphi, other than to write an occasional SO answer; I'm here for the assembly and x86 / sse tags.)

Comment: When you are writing assembly, it doesn't matter whether you are using C or Delphi. The reason your code is slower is because you are mixing Pascal code and assembly code. David and J... are right: never mix asm/pascal. You should write pure function starts with `asm` and contains no pascal code. You can still use Pascal type and variables.

Comment: The problem you had is that assembly does not support indirect pointers. When you use `movdqu xmm0, x`, `x` (`TDoubleQuadword`) is either a local variable or a parameter on the stack (forget Win64 ABI for now). It can be translated to `movdqu xmm0, [EBP+..]`. When you use `movdqu xmm0, p^`, `p` (`^TDoubleQuadword`), the translated assembly code is `movdqu xmm0, [[EBP+..]]`, which is not valid. So you have to load the address to a register (like `mov EBX, [EBP+...]`) before you can use it (`movdqu xmm0, [EBX]`).

Comment: @W.Chang I understand now; i have to hit the compiler over the head with a frying pan. :)   Put that in the form of an answer. As for mixing of asm and pascal, tracing through the generated assembly code, and nothing looks slow to me. It's not like it suddenly has to do a context switch every time you enter and leave an `asm` block. It's all instructions on a CPU.

Comment: Don't blame the compiler for not being able to use the pointer directly. The only compiler quirk is that mixing asm and pascal does not protect the use of extra registers needed to resolve the indirect loading. Some compilers can do it, but not Delphi.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that you can't get the compiler to do what you want it to do. As far as optimisation and performance goes, I think it's a little unfair to expect anybody answering the question to speak to that. At least when the question was first answered, you'd not stated the real world problem and the code in the question performs heap allocations before performing a single add. If the real problem involves adding long arrays, then a dedicated asm method to work on the array will be the way forward.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for inline assembler in Delphi isn't as comprehensive as it should be and a lot of the functionality is simply not documented. So I can't be sure of this, but to the best of my knowledge there is simply no support for the assembler statement that you are trying to write, where one operand is a local variable of pointer type.

I would strongly urge you to avoid mixing Pascal code and assembler code in the same function. It makes very hard to produce efficient code, and makes it very hard to manage register usage as you move between Pascal code and assembler code in the same function.

I personally make it a rule never to mix Pascal and inline assembler. Always write pure assembler functions. For instance, for 32 bit code you would write a complete program like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  PDoubleQuadword = ^TDoubleQuadword;
  TDoubleQuadword = record
    v1: UInt64;
    v2: UInt64;
  end;

function AddDoubleQuadword(const dqw1, dqw2: TDoubleQuadword): TDoubleQuadword;
asm
  movdqu xmm0, [eax]
  movdqu xmm1, [edx]
  paddq  xmm0, xmm1
  movdqu [ecx], xmm0
end;

procedure AlignedStuff;
var
  x, y: PDoubleQuadword;
begin
  New(x);
  x.v1 := $0000000000000001;
  x.v2 := $0000000000000005;

  New(y);
  y.v1 := $0000000000000002;
  y.v2 := $0000000000000007;

  x^ := AddDoubleQuadword(x^, y^);

  Writeln(x.v1, ', ', x.v2);
end;

begin
  AlignedStuff;
  Readln;
end.
```

This program outputs:

```
3, 12
```

Or you could use a record with operators:

```
type
  PDoubleQuadword = ^TDoubleQuadword;
  TDoubleQuadword = record
    v1: UInt64;
    v2: UInt64;
    class operator Add(const dqw1, dqw2: TDoubleQuadword): TDoubleQuadword;
  end;

class operator TDoubleQuadword.Add(const dqw1, dqw2: TDoubleQuadword): TDoubleQuadword;
asm
  movdqu xmm0, [eax]
  movdqu xmm1, [edx]
  paddq  xmm0, xmm1
  movdqu [ecx], xmm0
end;
```

And then at the call site you have:

```
x^ := x^ + y^;
```

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
   asm
        mov eax, x
        mov edx, y
        movdqu xmm0, DQWORD PTR [eax]   //move unaligned double quadwords (xmm0 := x)
        movdqu xmm1, DQWORD PTR [edx]  //move unaligned double quadwords (xmm1 := y)

        paddq  xmm0, xmm1     //add packed quadword integers    (xmm0 := xmm0 + xmm1)
        movdqu DQWORD PTR [eax], xmm0  //move unaligned double quadwords (v1 := xmm0)
    end;

 IntToStr(x.v1)+', '+IntToSTr(x.v2);  prints 3,12
```

Comment: What if the Pascal function is also using `eax` and `edx`?

Comment: @David Heffernan  eax and edx can be freely modified inside inline asm

Comment: Not if the Pascal code in the same function is also using the registers.

Comment: EAX and EDX are volatile registers. You can modify them without any problems. It might mean that the optimizer can't be as efficient as otherwise (I would guess that an asm block "clears" the register variables and thus necessitates its reload after the block end), but no consequences (other than loss of optimization) should come from using EAX, EDX (and ECX) registers in inline asm blocks.

Comment: Actually I don't know if the compiler does guard against this, but even if it does the performance implication is poor. Just don't mix Pascal and asm.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  The compiler does not guard against this.  I don't think it can.

Comment: @J... So you agree with me that this is the path to pain?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes.  I never mix asm/pascal either - the ABI is valid when you enter the method... not so halfway through.

Comment: Author asked about possibility to perform specific action - load xmm register having address -  I've shown how to do it. He is experienced enough to make real code safe.

Comment: @HeartWare: fortunately, inline asm blocks are quite seldom these days, and indeed, they hinder the optimizer. They were used more in (very) old versions, but these did not have any notable optimizations anyway.

Comment: @J: Of course, the compiler *can*. Just insert "PUSH EAX/PUSH ECX/PUSH EDX" right at the "ASM" keyword, and "POP EDX/POP ECX/POP EAX" at the "END" keyword. Or save the values in local variables [EBP-xx]. Or just reload the values at the "END" keyword that currently were in registers (after having saved them if they were calculations and not merely loaded values like the "Self" pointer). It would influence the optimizer, as it would be (next to) impossible to determine what your ASM block did, so the compiler would have to scratch all previous assumptions and reload everything, but...

Comment: @J: Come to think of it, PUSH/POP or SAVE/LOAD probably wouldn't work either, as - like I said above - it would be next to impossible for the optimizer to deduce what your ASM block had done, so it would probably be the last option: Dumping everything and starting from scratch... But still certainly doable in the sense that it woulnd't harm anything, execution wise - "only" speed wise due to optimizer having to start all over...

Comment: @J: And ABI is not relevant in 32-bit code, which is what we are talking about here, and is probably the main reason that inline assembler isn't allowed in 64-bit code, only pure assembler routines...

Comment: @HeartWare Surely ABI is relevant on all platforms?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As I understand "ABI", it is the calling convention used in 64-bit code, and has no bearing in 32-bit code...

Comment: @HeartWare No, each platform has an ABI, including x86

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If you say so. Anyway, it still has no bearing in 32-bit, as there's no requirement in 32-bit of any specific stack alignment or stack frame or shadow stack (the ABI is always ok). Parameters are accessed via EBP, not ESP, and as long as you don't destroy this, there's no problem with stack frames in inline assembly. You also don't need to keep track of any stack alignment or anything in 32-bit assembler, so as long as you don't do strange things to the stack or EBP (and preserve EBX, ESI and EDI) you are safe to do whatever you want to all the 32-bit registers in your block.

Comment: @Heart You don't need to take my word for what ABI is. You can just do a websearch.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Whatever ABI is, it still has no relevance in 32-bit, as it is always valid, and not - as J said - suddenly invalid half-way through a 32-bit function (unless you construct a scenario just to destroy it). There's no ABI to care about being valid or not in an inline ASM block in 32-bit.

Comment: @HeartWare What I mean is that the ABI guarantees where you can find the parameters passed to the method at the moment you enter the method.  As soon as any pascal code is allowed to run, however, the state of the registers and stack can become unknown.

Comment: @J: Not the stack. The stack is always properly aligned at entry to an ASM block in 32-bit. And only if you use Register calling convention (which is the default, I know), do you care about parameters to the routine becoming invalid as registers are modified. If you mark your routine with PASCAL calling convention you don't have to worry about anything other than preserving EBX/ESI/EDI(+EBP/ESP) registers in a 32-bit inline assembly block. Also, if you don't access passed parameters in your block, you don't care about the calling convention. All local variables are always OK to access by name.

Comment: @HeartWare Yes, you'd have to access them by name (which we don't want to do) because you don't know whether those values are still where they were supposed to be or whether they have moved or have been overwritten.  Either you want the compiler to do its job or you don't - mixing pascal and asm is almost pointless.  If we're using asm it's for performance.  If you're going to the trouble of hand tuning in assembly then why would you leave the job half done?  If the compiler doesn't have enough sense to optimize properly then why should we trust it to manage our variables?

Comment: @HeartWare and J...: It is not possible in Delphi, but e.g. GCC lets you tell the compiler exactly which registers will be used for what, which registers will be clobbered, etc. Delphi could do that too, but until then, optimizations are pretty hard to do. Probably also the reason you can't inline asm functions.

Comment: @J... Optimization is not the only (but yes, it is the main) reason to use assembler. There are things you can't easily do in Pascal (or at all) and which require assembler.